Linking a text box with a calendar date box
I am trying to create a calendar in Excel. I am trying to link the boxes with the text in up to the ones with the dates so it doesn't become misaligned.
I currently have my date boxes as =WORKDAY(TODAY(), 0) and also have the date as a text in the cell above. Below there are weekly tasks which need doing. Can these below text boxes with the tasks be linked to the date so they do not become misaligned?
Apologies if this is an easy task or if it is not possible, my Excel is very basic and I am just trying to learn, so any help is appreciated :)

Post sample dates. What do you mean by misaligned?

@Harun24hr So the week runs from 05/07/2024 (Friday) - 11/07/2024 (Thursday). Each day that goes by, the date will shift left so when it comes to Monday (08/07/2024) that will be the furthest left date on my weekly calendar. However, when the shift happens, the text boxes underneath do not shift also. So the tasks for Monday (08/07/2024) will stay and be underneath the date for Tuesday (09/07/2024).

I think I understand what you are looking for, but I've done it slightly different. There's a main task list and you can add a date next to each task (this will allow you to easily update tasks in case you need to change the dates).
For reference, "Today's Triumphs" is in cell A1.

First, create the Task List Table with the Date in column A and Task Description in column B. Then select all cells for the table and call the table "AllTasks" (you can change it at the end to whatever you like, the formulas should update).

Cell B1, provide the current date:

=WORKDAY(TODAY(),0)


Cell A2, counts total tasks for the day:

=CONCAT("Total Tasks to Complete: ",COUNTIF(AllTasks[[#All],[Task Start Date]],$A$5))


Cell A3, returns all tasks for that day:

=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF(IFERROR(MATCH(AllTasks[Task List],IF($B1=AllTasks[Task Start Date],AllTasks[Task
   List]),0),"")=MATCH(ROW(AllTasks[Task List]),ROW(AllTasks[Task
   List])),AllTasks[Task List],""))

Extra Credit: Out of Office Table to prevent scheduling conflicts.
Apply conditional formatting to the "AllTasks" table.

Formula:

=COUNTIF($D:$D,$A5)>0


Applies to:

=$A$5:$B$35

